# Convert string of list to python list

Tags: python, sql, string, converters

I downloaded a csv table from a database using SQL. One of the fields has values like so:

```
'[0.1234,0.0,0.0]'
```

I want to convert this string to a python list to get the first value. I only know how to convert strings to ints and floats... is there any way to de-string this object? The table I got from SQL is from a web-based viewer, I'm not getting it from my command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the substring from index `1` to index `-1` and then split it using the comma as a delimiter. In python

```py
array = variable[1:-1].split(',')
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure it is always valid list syntax, you could use"

```
myList = eval('[0.1234,0.0,0.0]')
```

Or if the value itself has quotes `'` in it, you can slice those off

```
value = "'[0.1234,0.0,0.0]'"
myList = eval(value[1:-1])
```

Then to get the first value you just

```
myList[0]
```